# How to compile a static library in Linux?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I have a question: How to compile a static library in Linux with `gcc`, i.e. I need to compile my source code into a file named out.a. Is it sufficient to simply compile with the command `gcc -o out.a out.c`? I'm not quite familiar with `gcc`, hope anyone can give me a hand.

Comment: check [this](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/all-about-static-libraries-in-c-cea57990c495)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

See [Creating a shared and static library with the gnu compiler [gcc]](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/GCC/create-libraries/index)

```
gcc -c -o out.o out.c
```

`-c` means to create an intermediary object file, rather than an executable.

```
ar rcs libout.a out.o
```

This creates the static library.  `r` means to insert with replacement, `c` means to create a new archive, and `s` means to write an index.  As always, see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) for more info.

Comment: `-o` isn't required. The output will be the same (`out.o`)

Answer (score 122):

Here a full makefile example:

**makefile**

```
TARGET = prog

$(TARGET): main.o lib.a
    gcc $^ -o $@

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
     
lib.a: lib1.o lib2.o
    ar rcs $@ $^

lib1.o: lib1.c lib1.h
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

lib2.o: lib2.c lib2.h
    gcc -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a $(TARGET)
```

explaining the makefile:

- `target: prerequisites` - the rule head
- `$@` - means the target
- `$^` - means all prerequisites
- `$<` - means just the first prerequisite
- `ar` - a Linux tool to create, modify, and extract from archives [see the man pages for further information](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar). The options in this case mean:

  - `r` - replace files existing inside the archive
  - `c` - create an archive if not already present
  - `s` - create an object-file index into the archive

**To conclude**: The static library under Linux is nothing more than an archive of object files.

**main.c** *using the lib*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lib.h"

int main ( void )
{
    fun1(10);
    fun2(10);
    return 0;
}
```

**lib.h** *the libs main header*

```
#ifndef LIB_H_INCLUDED
#define LIB_H_INCLUDED

#include "lib1.h"
#include "lib2.h"

#endif
```

**lib1.c** *first lib source*

```
#include "lib1.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void fun1 ( int x )
{
    printf("%i\n",x);
}
```

**lib1.h** *the corresponding header*

```
#ifndef LIB1_H_INCLUDED
#define LIB1_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern “C” {
#endif

void fun1 ( int x );

#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif

#endif /* LIB1_H_INCLUDED */
```

**lib2.c** *second lib source*

```
#include "lib2.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void fun2 ( int x )
{
    printf("%i\n",2*x);
}
```

**lib2.h** *the corresponding header*

```
#ifndef LIB2_H_INCLUDED
#define LIB2_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern “C” {
#endif

void fun2 ( int x );

#ifdef __cplusplus
   }
#endif

#endif /* LIB2_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: it would have helped to point out what the commands do, and what they intend to achieve. especially in this case the `ar` needs explanation, as it is the key to creating the static library.

Comment: The `ar` program creates, modifies, and extracts from archives, which are a single files holding a collection of other files in a structure that makes it possible to retrieve the original individual files. `ar` creates an index to the symbols defined in relocatable object modules in the archive when you specify the modifier s. (see `man ar`)

Comment: please add following lines to your header to support ```c++``` compiler:

```#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
.
.
.


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Generate the object files with gcc, then use `ar` to bundle them into a static library.