# compiling stasm for mac

Tags: ios, linux, macos, opencv

I'm try to to build the stasm library on my mac and hopefully port it to the iphone.
stasm download: http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/download.html

I am using the makefile for linux provided.
after some changes to header include paths for libjpeg and opencv, I am stuck with this error

```
g++ -c ../stasm/violajones.cpp -O3 -Wall -pedantic -I/home/john/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv -I../gsl -I../gsl/gsl -I../image -I../jpeg -I../mat -I../rowley -I../stasm -I../tasm 
In file included from ../stasm/violajones.cpp:24:
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:33: error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory 
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64:33: error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:65:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:66:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:67:38: error: opencv2/video/tracking.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:68:45: error: opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:69:35: error: opencv2/flann/flann.hpp: No such file or directory 
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:70:39: error: opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:71:43: error: opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:72:37: error: opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:79:37: error: opencv2/core/internal.hpp: No such file or directory In file included
from ../stasm/violajones.cpp:25:
/opt/local/include/opencv/highgui.h:47:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/highgui.h:48:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
```

the original makefile is uploaded here https://github.com/tsaizhenling/stuff/blob/master/makefile

i have tried changing the directory as trojanfoe suggested
but still same error :(

I have opencv and opencv2 residing in /opt/local/include/

**Update:**

tried J-16 SDiZ's suggestion and this brought me forward. I had to remove the pedantic flag but i'm still stuck with the following error

> g++ -c ../stasm/tab.cpp -O3 -Wall -I/opt/local/include/opencv
>   -I/opt/local/include -I../gsl -I../gsl/gsl -I../image -I../jpeg -I../mat -I../rowley -I../stasm -I../tasm make: *** No rule to make target `-lm', needed by`stasm'.  Stop.

makefile is updated

**Update:**

Finally got everything fixed with help from J-16 SDiZ.

had to update the linker flags because opencv changed the library names

makefile is updated in case anyone needs it

Comment: Looks like it's looking for OpenCV stuff in `/opt/local/include` and yet you have specified `/home/john/OpenCV-2.1.0/include`.  Please post the `Makefile`, as it looks broken.

Comment: the changed names helped me compile it on Ubuntu precise!

Comment: @tzl Hi, I am building stasm for iOS. Thanks for this question and your new Makefile, I generated a bundle of .o files and the binary executable files. But what I want is something like library or framework I can use in my Xcode project. Do you know how can I do it? Or what did you do after get all sources compiled on a Mac? Thank you for any information!

Comment: hi, glad to know the makefile helped you out, I did not procced on beyong getting the executable to work on my mac because it was no longer required. you can checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734719/howto-compile-a-static-library-in-linux that tells you how to generate a static library from object files

Comment: Hi have you done with integrating STASM with IOS? How was the performance with real time video capture? Is it fast? Can you tell the speed in terms of FPS?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to import it to iOS? I'm trying to do it too, any luck?

Comment: hi, sorry this was a really long time ago. If memory serves me right, we eventualy did not use it to build the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
INCL=\
    -I$(OPENCV_HOME)/include/opencv\
    -I../gsl\
```

to

```
INCL=\
    -I$(OPENCV_HOME)/include/opencv\
    -I$(OPENCV_HOME)/include \
    -I../gsl\
```

And you should not use `${LIB}` in the dependency.

change

```
something: xxxxxx $(LIBS) $(OBJ)
```

to

```
something: xxxxxx $(OBJ)
```

I think you should learn how Makefile works, this is a makefile problem.

Comment: thanks this change brought me forward abit more. I had to remove a -pedantic flag. I have now run into another error make: *** No rule to make target `-lm', needed by `stasm'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

There are Mac/Linux build scripts for Stasm here:
https://github.com/juan-cardelino/stasm

You can build for iOS easily using this:
https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/wiki/HowTo