# Compile STASM on mac

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

i'm trying to compile STASM on my macbook pro.
I followed this post [compiling stasm for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857474/compiling-stasm-for-mac) and i put the makefile https://github.com/tsaizhenling/stuff/blob/master/makefile in my stasm folder.

But when i try to do:

```
make -f makefile
```

it returns this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../apps/mdiff/mdiff.cpp', needed by `mdiff.o'.  Stop.
```

Hope in your help!

Luca

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc makefile error: "No rule to make target ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

Comment: Judging by the makefile, I think it should be in your build directory, not in the root.

Comment: @Cyber I had now modify my makefile because the file mdiff.cpp is in ../apps/mdiff/mdiff.cpp, but the error still the same like now you can see in the updated question

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry, i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at this: https://github.com/juan-cardelino/stasm ?
The readme includes instructions on how to use the provided makefiles on a Unix system.

Comment: Thank you, i was just looking that... it has solved my problem!

Comment: Great! Just a note: I don't know what you are going to use STASM for but I found that for me it was too slow. I found Face Analysis SDK and it was way less laggy.