# Create a single .o file

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Howto compile a static library in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734719/howto-compile-a-static-library-in-linux)

I'm trying to compile a library that will be used further.

For each cpp file, of this library, is generating a .o file. How can I make the same compilation with only one .o file?

Comment: You link all the .o files together to make an .a file.

Comment: Why? Sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @SethCarnegie how can I do that?

Comment: @Victor `ar rcs some.a 1.o 2.o ...`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734719/726361 (I assume it's a static library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not build a single .o file from multiple C++ source files. Compilers just can't handle that.

If the library comes with a proper build infrastructure (like Makefiles), that should make a `libXXX.a` or `libXXX.so` file that you can reference from your own project.

If the library does *not* create a lib-file by itself, you can create one with

```
ar -r libXXX.a <list of .o files>
```

Comment: "*You can not build a single .o file from multiple C++ source files.*" -- Actually, he **can**, he just doesn't want to. As you correctly observe, he wants to build a `.a` library.