# How to combine assembly functions in .h file?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, header-files

Might be a duplicate but i wasn't able to find a answer for my question.

Usually if you want to import multiple functions from different c files in one main class, one would make a .h file and list up all functions from the .c sources.

My problem is, that all functions are wridden in .asm files. I used `extern void asmFunc(int i, char c);` to use the function in further code, but they become more and more and i don't want to end up with 200 of those extern lines at the beginning of my main. How can i create a library.h with all assembly functions so i can just write `#include "library.h"` at the beginning of my main class?

EDIT:
I think i didn't give enough specific information:

- I use MINGW gcc and NASM to compile c and asm files
- I have to compile all files to .o first so i can match them
- The first answer i got didn't work because my compile chain is a bit complicated thanks to the restrictions i have on Windows (i want Linux back)

It looks like this:
I got a folder containing three folders with seperated library-like structures: bwt (basic window toolkit), io and std (stuff like strlen)
They are compiled into bwt.o io.o and std.o.

Now i want to make a .h file for each of them so i can `#include "bwt.h"` in all kernel classes which need them. How do i get gcc to realize, that all functions in bwt.h are defined in bwt.o?

Comment: Have you tried putting all of the declarations in library.h?

Comment: Are you sure about the difference between a header file, and a library? Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/3775615). What you need to do is put all the declarations into a header file (library.h) which you can include in all files where it is used. Then, you need to compile a library (static: library.a or dynamic: library.so) which contains the code for the lib. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734727/3775615).

Comment: Yes i am, usually i use .a for libraries but for this special case i only need the .o files since the code is not a usual application but a kernel so i can skip the step with .a I just want to get rid of the 142 extern lines and replace them with #include "alibstd.h"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a .o file, it doesn't matter that the source for those routines is assembly.  As long as you know how to call them as C functions that's what matters.

So put all of your `extern` declarations for the assembly functions in library.h, then `#include "library.h"` in your main file.  Then you can link them.

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o program main.o asmfunctions.o
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Make a file
2. Save the file as `library.h` (same folder as your C file)
3. Put your extern declarations* in the file
4. Add `#include "library.h"` in your C file

`#include` is *literally* copy-paste. You can put some code into another file, and then you can `#include` that file, and the compiler pretends you wrote the code in the main file directly. That's how it works.

* by the way, you don't need to write `extern` when declaring functions - only variables.